# Convert Excel/Access data to Notepad

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

So here is what I want to do

I work in contact center -- where we gather information and need to perform action. To perform the action, we have to send details to other workers. To do it quickly -- what I want is that I can gather information in Excel or Access like this:

I have following Excel spreadsheet:

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

Now when I pressed button, I want it to be converted into notepad like this:

[image: Notepad outcome]

I am just wondering whether it is possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, you can do it with VBA. But StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. You will need to start on your own and if you have specific questions with the code you wrote you can come back and ask a code specific question.

Comment: Of course not! I know VBa a bit I just wanna know whether it is possible or not @Peh

Comment: What do you mean by "Of course not!"? I don't understand you. You asked whether it is possible. And I answered yes it is possible, which is the correct answer to this question.

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.org/write_to_a_text_file.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible. (since you've tagged ms-access).
Loop through a record set and then build a string.
You can do whatever you want with the string afterwards.

```
'declare
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rstSQL As Recordset 'recordset for SQL
Dim str As String

'open a recordset ...
strSQL = "select * from tablename"
Set rstSQL = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot, dbSeeChanges)
'perform actions with recordset
With rstSQL
    If .RecordCount >= 1 Then
        .MoveFirst
        Do Until .EOF
            str = str & "username:" & !UserName & vbCrLf
            str = str & "incidentid:" & !incidentid & vbCrLf
            str = str & "summary:" & !summary & vbCrLf
            str = str & "notes:" & !notes & vbCrLf
            str = str & "poi:" & !poi & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            str = str & vbCrLf & "===================="
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
End With
'close recordset
If Not rstSQL Is Nothing Then rstSQL.Close
Set rstSQL = Nothing

'output the text
debug.print str
```